Proving (p → r) ∨ (q → r) ≡ (p ∧ q) → r
So I do understand that this could be much more easily proven using basic logical equivalences as follows:
(p → r) ∨ (q → r)
≡ (¬p ∨ r) ∨ (¬q ∨ r)
≡ (¬p ∨ ¬q) ∨ r
≡ ¬(p ∧ q) ∨ r
≡ (p ∧ q) → r
However, since (p → r) ∨ (q → r) ≡ (p ∧ q) → r is the same as (p → r) ∨ (q → r) ↔ (p ∧ q) → r being a tautology, I thought why not try proving the bi-conditional statement by doing direct proof both directions:
For the ((p → r) ∨ (q → r)) → ((p ∧ q) → r) part:
To prove this conditional, we'd have to assume (p → r) ∨ (q → r) is true and show (p ∧ q) → r becomes true from it. To show (p ∧ q) → r is true, we'd have to assume (p ∧ q) is true and r is true. Hence, we'd be assuming both (p → r) ∨ (q → r) and (p ∧ q) are true. (p → r) ∨ (q → r) means at least one of the 2 implications that give the consequence of r is true, and since both p and q are true this means r must also be true. Hence proof complete for forward implication.
For the ((p ∧ q) → r) → ((p → r) ∨ (q → r)) part:
This one was the main point of confusion (and what my question is all about). Proving a implication with a disjunction as the consequent was something I was unsure how to do (and what I've seen many other people have asked too online unsure about). So I just did some logical equivalences (where for propositions x, y, and z, [x → (y ∨ z)] ≡ [(x ∧ ¬y) -> z]). to get this expression is equivalent to ((p ∧ q) → r) ∧ p ∧ ¬r) → (q → r). Therefore, I first assumed LHS was true, then assume q is true. Assuming LHS true means all propositions in conjunction are true, meaning p and ¬r should be true (meaning r is false). So LHS is hence ((T ∧ T) → F) ∧ T ∧ T) = F ∧ T ∧ T = F. Hence there's a contradiction. This last part/contradiction is what's confusing me here. What do I take from this part of the proof exactly? Is the entire implication now proven true vacuously or something? I'm lost here essentially.
Kindly please let me know.


So LHS is hence ((T ∧ T) → F) ∧ T ∧ T) = F ∧ T ∧ T = F. Hence there's a contradiction.

To be clear, this "LHS" is $((p\land q)\to r)\land p\land\neg r\land q$, the antecedent of the implication $(((p\land q)\to r)\land p\land\neg r\land q) \to(r)$.

Is the entire implication now proven true vacuously or something?

Yes.  If an antecedent is a contradiction then the implication is a tautology.
Which is what we want to prove (well, a step along the way, anyway).

All that remains is to prove $(((p\land q)\to r)\land p\land\neg r\land q) \to(r)$ is equivalent to $(((p\land q)\to r)\to((p\to r)\lor(q \to r))$, by the rules at your disposal.

Ok so basically if I further simplify my "LHS" to what you have here by using A -> (B -> C) = (A && B) -> C, then I'd see LHS is really just the conjunction of an implication and it's negation, (A && !A), which is a contradiction := always false proposition. Hence implication is proven vacuously.

Here might be an approach to consider.
Suppose $\left(p \land q\right) \implies r$ is true.
This means one of the following cases holds:
(1) $\left(p \land q\right)$ is true and $r$ true (i.e. both $p$ and $q$ are true),
or
(2) $\left(p \land q\right)$ is false (i.e. one or both $p$ or $q$ is false) and $r$ true, or
(3) $\left(p \land q\right)$ is false (i.e. one or both $p$ or $q$ is false) and $r$ false.
This implies that in any of the above cases either $\left(p \implies r\right)$ is true or $\left(q \implies r\right)$ is true or both, which is $\left(p \implies r\right) \lor \left(q \implies r\right)$ is true.
